# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 in Python - updating setuptools doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, spyder

I'm new to Python, having coded exclusively in R before this.

I'm trying to install a few modules and keep running into the same problem.

```
pip install fiona
Collecting fiona
  Using cached Fiona-1.8.17.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\forpython\envs\virtual\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Jonah Foong\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hshotvxk\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Jonah Foong\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hshotvxk\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Jonah Foong\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-hjs8r8t5'
         cwd: C:\Users\Jonah Foong\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hshotvxk\fiona\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I've trawled the forums and looked for past solutions, each to no avail. I have updated setuptools, but the error still appears. I am also running this in a virtual environment.

What seems to be the problem here? It's very frustrating to face issues installing modules on my first day using Python. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

PS: I'm running Python 3.8.5 on Spyder, if that helps.

Comment: Try installing Fiona and GDAL from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#fiona).

Comment: If you're new to Python, you should downloa and install Anaconda instead, and install `fiona` with `conda`. Using pip to install packages (specially scientific ones) is reserved to very knowledgeable users.